# Consistency check for a linked-list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, big-o, consistency

First of all, what exactly is a list invariant in linked-list?

How to check if a linked-list is consistent using algorithm that runs in O(n) time and O(1) additional memory?

Answer (score 2):

In a doubly-linked list, the invariant is that each node is the predecessor of its successor.

Consider an implementation where each node maintains two pointers, one `succ` pointer pointing to its successor node, and one `pred` pointer pointing to its predecessor node.

In a correct list, the pointers are layed out like this:

[image: doubly linked list with 3 nodes]

Note that when you follow the `succ` pointer from one node to the next, you can always use the `pred` pointer to go back to your original node. Each operation manipulating the list must make sure that this condition is kept intact.

A list that violates this invariant might look like this:

[image: doubly linked list with broken invariant]

This could for example happen if an incorrectly implemented insert operation tried to insert a node `n2` in the middle of the list, but forgot to update the `pred` pointer of  `n3`.

Checking this invariant is straightforward: Iterate through the list by traversing along the `succ` pointers (`O(n)`) and keep the last visited node in a memory buffer (`O(1)`). Then check at each node whether the `pred` pointer of the current node points to the last visited node.

If you know the end node of the list as well, check whether the last node you arrive at (the one with no successor) is the expected end node.

Note that with a single linked list, no such invariant exists.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem I have is I'm dealing with single linked-list. How can I check for consistency if there's no invariant for single linked-list?

Comment: @YukiKurokawa Well, what do you _want_ to check? There is no natural invariant for the single-linked data structure as such, so I guess there is some property for the specific problem you are trying to solve that can serve as an invariant. I'd suggest you open a new question including additional information on the concrete problem and see if you can get a more specific answer there. But please take your time to properly flesh out that question before posting, to avoid getting another answer that won't help you.